# Lambda add incremented elements to list

Tags: c#, lambda

If I have a number and I need to increment it n times and add them to a list, is there a way to do this in 1 line in lambda?

For eg.

```
int n = 5; //5 elements.
int x = 10; // starts at 10
//do stuff
List<int> list;
//list now contains: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
```

Comment: You say 5 elements, then list 6 as the expected output....... edit nm then.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to construct a list with 5 elements from a given starting point, incrementing by one, you can use `Enumerable.Range`.

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(10, 5).ToList();
```

To add those to a pre-existing list, combine it with `AddRange`

```
list.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(10, 5));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(x,n).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun using lambda expression and closure: 
(I like `Enumerable.Range()` but also I like a fun whilst approaching different solutions)

```
var list = new List<int>();            
Action<int, int> generator = (x, n) => { while ( n-- > 0) list.Add(x++); };
generator(10, 5);
```